# Is anticommutativity same as antisymmetry for order relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

I'm trying to understand if order relation (over reals) $$a>b$$ is anticommutative, that is if I can say that $$a>b = -(b>a) = -b > -a$$
I'm in doubt as [Wikipedia page for anti-commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticommutative_property) doesn't include order relation. Perhaps I conflate different terms (together with converse property)?

Comment: What does $-(b > a)$ mean?

Comment: (anti-)commutativity is a property of *operations*, (anti-)symmetry is a property of *relations*. The order relation is, well, a *relation*, not an *operation*.

Comment: @lisyarus oh, indeed, perhaps I confused those because > is often an operation in computer programming.